# Write the english sentence represented by the logical expression.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$\neg(S \land L) \lor S$$
$$S = \text {John is lucky.}$$
$$L = \text {John is smart.}$$

1. John is not both smart and lucky, or he is smart.
2. It is not true that John is smart and lucky, or he is smart.

Are 1 and 2 equivalent?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, although 2 could be misread as "It is not true that [John is smart and lucky or he is smart]".

Comment: I would suggest you include the word "either".  "Either John is not both smart and lucky, or he is smart." and "Either It is not true that John is smart and lucky, or he is smart."  That makes it clearer that the main connector is the "or" not the "and".  I would also say that (1) is better standard English than (2).

Comment: @lemontree @user247327! That very helpful. Thanks.